# Is there a function that gives the ideal probability distribution of a measurement in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, measurement

I want to compare the theoretical output of a circuit measurement with the actual output from a real quantum computer. I can approximate the ideal output by running the circuit on a simulator.  However when you're measuring a state in superposition, the results you get from a simulator are still nondeterministic, making them not ideal for comparison.

For instance, when measuring a single qubit in even superposition (the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$, the ideal result would be that you measure $|0\rangle$ with probability $0.5$ and $|1\rangle$ with probability $0.5$. However, when running on a simulator, you might naturally get $|0\rangle$ with probability $0.501$ and $|1\rangle$ with probability $0.499$:

[image]

In other words, knowing that the theoretical probability of obtaining state $|\phi\rangle$ when measuring a state $|\psi\rangle$ is $\langle\phi|\psi\rangle$, is there a function in Qiskit to calculate this value from a circuit or state, or to get the ideal probability distribution that I can compare my actual distribution against?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `statevector_simulator` to return the statevector of your system. From this statevector, you can see the theoretical probability of obtaining each possible state for your system. For example:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.x(0)

sim = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

job = execute(qc, sim)

print(job.result().get_statevector(qc))
```

will print out 
`[0.+0.j 1.+0.j 0.+0.j 0.+0.j]`. Each element refers to a possible 2-qubit state. The 0th element would refer to state `00`, the 1st refers to `01`, the 2nd to `10`, and the 3rd to `11`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sure, I can do a bit of processing to find the probabilities this way - I was wondering if there was any faster way to do this. If not, I can do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the probabilities snapshot. Enter a snapshot as a circuit instruction:

```
circuit.snapshot_probabilities(label, qubits)
```

Then after execution get the probabilities from the result, see the documentation of `Result.data`.

Comment: Note that this requires something like:
```
from qiskit.providers.aer.extensions.snapshot_probabilities import *
```